# ConstraintLayout stable release?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Is ConstraintLayout is safe to be used in Production ?
Current version is beta 4.

'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'

beta in naming forced me in asking this.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to try it by yourself, even the non beta library have bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beta 4 should be pretty stable. The thing with layouts is that if they work for your app, they won't change. We are busy working on the next release which fixes a few corner case issues and improve performances. Aside from the *library*, the editor in Android Studio 2.2 has issues if the layout is not the top layout. Android Studio 2.3 improves things drastically.

Comment: Constraint Layout is broken. It never works with softInputMode. The entire view jumps when keyboard pops up. Is there a fix in Constraint Layout? Some piece of code or something without having to completely use a different layout like RelativeLayout?

Answer (score 0):

It has MANY bugs.
If you can create a layout it's reliable.
But creating a layout is a nightmare: constraints being continously deleted, lost constraints even if you don't make any change, problems with CardView(s)...

Comment: Which version of android studio ? I highly recommend 2.3 for the editor. As for ConstraintLayout *the library* it's pretty stable. Library != Editor.